# Let $X=\{0,1\}^{\Bbb R}$ and each $\{0,1\}$ discrete. Show that $E=\{\chi_A : A \subset \Bbb R \text{ discrete}\}$ is dense in $X$.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X=\{0,1\}^{\Bbb R}$ and each $\{0,1\}$ discrete. We can express $X$ as characteristic functions as follows $X=\{\chi_A \mid A \subset \Bbb R\}$. Show that $E=\{\chi_A : A  \subset \Bbb R \text{ discrete}\}$ is dense in $X$.

$E$ is dense if $U \cap E\ne \emptyset$ for any $U$ open in $X$. It suffices to show that $B \cap E \ne \emptyset$ for any $B$ in the basis of the product topology?

If $B\in \mathcal{B}$, then $$B=pr_{i_0}^{-1}(U_{i_0}) \cap \dots \cap pr_{i_n}^{-1}(U_{i_n})$$ where $U_{i_n} \subset X_{i_n}$. Since each $X_{i_n}$ is discrete $U_{i_n} = \{0\}, \{1\}, X, \emptyset$. Now $$pr_{i_n}^{-1}(U_{i_n})  = \begin{cases} 0, U_{i_n}=\{0\}\\1,  U_{i_n}=\{1\} \\ \emptyset,  U_{i_n}=\emptyset \\ X,  U_{i_n}=X\end{cases}$$

so in any case $B$ must intersect $X$ impying $B \cap E \ne \emptyset$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is correct. Note that, for each $x\in\Bbb R$, $\operatorname{pr}_x^{-1}(\emptyset)=\emptyset$ and $\operatorname{pr}_x^{-1}(\{0,1\})=X$. It follows that you only have to deal with the case in which $U_x$ is $\{0\}$ or $\{1\}$.

If each $U_{x_k}$ is $\{0\}$, then $\chi_\emptyset$ will belong to $E\cap\left(\bigcap_{k=1}^n\operatorname{pr}_{x_k}^{-1}(U_{x_k})\right)$. Otherwise, you have $U_{x_k}=\{1\}$ if and only if $k\in K$ for some non-empty subset $K$ of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. But then $\chi_{K}\in E\cap\left(\bigcap_{k=1}^n\operatorname{pr}_{x_k}^{-1}(U_{x_k})\right)$.

Comment: Should $\operatorname{pr}_x^{-1}(\{0,1\})=\Bbb R$ be $\operatorname{pr}_x^{-1}(\{0,1\})= X$ instead of $\Bbb R$? By definition $$\operatorname{pr}_x^{-1}(\{0,1\})=\{x \in X \mid \operatorname{pr}_x(x) \in \{0,1\} \}$$ and this should be all of $X$?

Comment: Yes. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In fact the even smaller subset $D:=\{\chi_F: F \subseteq \Bbb R \text{ finite }\}$ is dense in $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb R}$.

A basic non-empty open subset $O$ of the product is of the form $O:=\prod_{x \in \Bbb R} U_x$ where $U_x= \{0,1\}$ exept for $x \in F \subseteq \Bbb R$ where $F$ is finite, where $U_x=\{0\}$ or $U_x=\{1\}$. Let $E=\{x \in F: U_x=\{1\}\}$ and note that $\chi_E \in O$ and so every basic non-empty open set intersects $D$ and $D$ is dense. Finite subsets are discrete in $\Bbb R$ so your set is also dense.